# GMPY2 - How to avoid gmpy2.floor() returning mpfr instead of mpz?

Tags: python-3.x, gmpy

After using `gmpy2.floor()` on an `mpz` variable:

```
 x = mpz(5)
 x = gmpy2.floor(x/256)
```

`x` has the type `mpfr` and not `mpz` anymore, even though to my understanding, floor always returns integers.

How can I avoid that?

I'm afraid using `x = mpz(gmpy2.floor(x/256))` will reduce the performance, wont it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gmpy2` wraps the `MPFR` library and it returns an `mpfr` as the result type.

See http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Integer-Related-Functions

FYI, Python 2.x returns a `float` from `math.floor`. The behavior was changed for Python 3.

If you are looking for the floor of integer division, you can use `//`.

```
>>> gmpy2.mpz(123456789)//256
mpz(482253)
```

Comment: Thank you casevh. One last question: What if I'm doing something like `math.floor(gmpy2.log2(mpz(2**1024)))` which returns `mpfr('1024.0')` There is probably no way to get an mpz back right?

Comment: I would avoid floating point operations as much as possible. How about `(2**1024).bit_length() - 1`?